# GSON Custom Deserializer for a primitive type and an array

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I have a JSON Response that might have different values.

```
"values": [
                    {
                        "type": "AAA",
                        "value": 3
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "BBB",
                        "value": [
                            {
                                "ABC": 8
                            },
                            {
                                "DEF": 9
                            },
                            {
                                "GHI": 9
                            },
                            {
                                "JKL": 8
                            },
                            {
                                "MNO": 9
                            },
                            {
                                "PQR": 9
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
```

Data Class

```
data class Values(
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    val type: String,
    @SerializedName("value")
    @Expose
    val value: Int)
```

As you can see `value` can be Int or another Json Array. Any ideas how to write a deserializer for this? The Android App is currently using the Int field (type AAA) and I am trying to integrate the potential Array Values (type BBB). Thank you.

Comment: Can you make the `value` a Json Array even if it is a single int value? I mean just add that int value to the json array and return it, because that would make the json array as the uniform type in all of your cases and will be much easier to model and thus easier to deserialize. I have a solution in mind if this happens i.e. if you have control over the data coming form the backend

Comment: I was looking on some related questions as well, with some scenarios just converting it to an array of primitive types. Unfortunately, I don't have any control of the nesting of data

Comment: One thing you can do is make a `List<Pair>` if both the key and the value of the json object are important to you and in the case where a single value comes in , just add any arbitrary key if you will not be using it. I can give you a detail solution in this case also, if you agree to proceed with this method below in the answer section, but just confirming with you first

Comment: Just like some below answers suggest, we will do custom deserialization and then change your model `value` to be a `List<Pair` rather than an int and I already described above how you can handle the single value case

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't convert to a List since there are key value pairs for the app

Comment: That's what I said a `List<Pair>`

Comment: Yup, I can't convert it since the key-value pair in `BBB` is defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you can have a sealed class `Value` with two sub-classes:

```
sealed class Value {
    /* type AAA */
    data class IntValue(val value: Int) : Value()
    /* type BBB */
    data class IntPairValue(val value: List<Pair<String, Int>>) : Value() 
}
```

and write a custom deserializer:

```
class ValueTypeDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Value?> {
    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement,
        typeOfT: Type,
        context: JsonDeserializationContext
    ): Value? {
        return when {
            json.isJsonPrimitive -> {
                Value.IntValue(json.asJsonPrimitive.asInt)
            }
            json.isJsonArray -> {
                val list = context.deserialize<List<Map<String, Int>>>(json, LIST_OF_MAP_TYPE)
                val pairs = list.map { e -> e.firstNotNullOf { (key, value) -> Pair(key, value) } }
                Value.IntPairValue(pairs)
            }
            else -> null
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val LIST_OF_MAP_TYPE = object : TypeToken<List<Map<String, Int>>>() {}.type
    }
}
```

Now you can apply this deserializer to a `"value"` field using `@JsonAdapter` annotation like:

```
data class Values(
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    val type: String,
    @SerializedName("value")
    @Expose
    @JsonAdapter(ValueTypeDeserializer::class)
    val value: Value
) {
    val optIntValue: Int?
        get() = (value as? Value.IntValue)?.value
    val optIntPairValue: List<Pair<String, Int>>?
        get() = (value as? Value.IntPairValue)?.value
}
```

Use `optIntValue` or `optIntPairValue` to access the value you're interested in.

Answer (score -1):

**Try with this code:**

```
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(); // this is your values object
            Object o = jsonObject.get("value");
            if (o instanceof JSONArray) {
                //this is jsonarray
            } else if (o instanceof JSONObject) {
                //this is jsonobject
            } else if (o instanceof Integer) {
                //this is int
            } else if (o instanceof String) {
                //this is String
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Hi @Praful Patel, I am currently using retrofit for mapping JSON Responses, and I am not manually mapping them

Comment: Then set value_object type to "Object" into your retrofit model class.
then you use my if condition to your activity or getter method.

Comment: As I have said, there is an existing use of the Int value, and I can't just change it because it will affect a lot of stuff

Answer (score -1):

First of all, in your case use manual parsing instead of auto parsing, because auto parsing may arise issues and also a bit complicated in this case. Now you need to change the request to "JsonObject".

Try this code...

```
try {
        JSONObject your_response=new JSONObject();

        JSONArray jsonArrayMain=your_response.getJSONArray("values");

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrayMain.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArrayMain.getJSONObject(i);
            String type=jsonObject.getString("type");

            Object o = jsonObject.get("value");
            if (o instanceof JSONArray) {
                //value is array
                JSONArray jsonArrayValue=jsonObject.getJSONArray("value");

                for (int j = 0; j <jsonArrayValue.length(); j++) {

                    JSONObject subJsonObject=jsonArrayValue.getJSONObject(j);
                    
                    Iterator<String> iterator = subJsonObject.keys();
                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        String key = iterator.next();
                        Log.i("====TAG","key:"+key +"--Value::"+subJsonObject.optString(key);
                    }
                }

            } else if (o instanceof String) {
                //value is string
                String value=jsonObject.getString("value");
            }
        }

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hope, it works. :)